# How to connect chip pin to either vcc or groud externally?

Tags: integrated-circuit, optoelectronics

I have a board that i use ic which one pin need to be externally decided to be connected to VCC or ground based on LED lightening

The schematic use this symbol for a connector to indicate this 
[image]

How can i implement this in my PCB ?

Comment: VCC is NOT the same thing as VSS.

Comment: Use a 3 pin jumper connector with a 2 pin shorting plug.

Comment: For a more permanent selection, placing two of the smallest SMT resistors your process can handle can be a solution, you can then place a zero-ohm resistor in one position.  If this is a supply pin you do then incur some extra inductance.   Trying to make the two resistors footprints share their common pad is where it maybe gets into debate territory.  There are also various designs for "solder bridges" can can theoretically be set by inclusion of paste on the stencil in that location, or not, but getting them right may require some process experience.

Comment: If you know which connection you need when you are designing the board, just show the appropriate connection on the schematic - then the required connection will be made on the board.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a picture of the typical setup to do this:
[image]

In your case you would use only 3 posts, the center being the pin you want to switch, and the ends being VCC and ground (VSS). These "breakaway" headers and shorting plugs are readily available from Digi-Key or Fry's, etc.

As one of the comments pointed out your diagram is labelled VSS and ground, which sounds incorrect.

The other comment suggests zero ohm resistors which is also a great solution if you don't need the flexibility of changing back and forth a lot. A "stuffing option" at the time of manufacture can select the correct setting.

Finally you could use solid state switches or a relay if you wanted to make the selection via a microcontroller or some other automatic method.